# Subscription and Favorite link on synonym tag uses wrong url

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, subscription

The tag [ria-services](/questions/tagged/ria-services) is a synonym for the tag [wcf-ria-services](/questions/tagged/wcf-ria-services) and the ToolTip displays the information of the master tag. Also all operations in the ToolTip like `frequent`, `info`, `top users`, `rss` and `edit` work on the master tag.

But the `Subscribe` uses the URL https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ria-services/subscription while i think it should use https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf-ria-services/subscription.

For `Favorite` it is the same case. It uses https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ria-services/favorite while it should be https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf-ria-services/favorite

The same is true for all the other synonyms of the tag [wcf-ria-services](/questions/tagged/wcf-ria-services) and i think all other synonyms of other tags have the same behavior.